# Update view's canvas outside of onDraw on Android

Tags: android, view, android-canvas

I need update a small portion of a custom view in order to display a small animation. The rest portion of the view has only static image. The most straightforward would be to obtain the canvas of the view and update only that particular portion directly. But I can't really find anyway to get the view's canvas object outside of the view::onDraw method.

The only alternative I know is this: call view::invalidate() with a specified rectangle to minimize the drawing flicker. I have the code to update the entire view within onDraw. So the best thing to do is to detect the clipping rect and only run the code to update the specified area, in order to minimize CPU usage as well?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I will try to answer this question myself to the best my knowledge so far.

1. There is no direct access to the canvas outside of the onDraw method.
2. Although we can detect the clipping rect with the function Canvas.getClipBounds(), the getClipBounds function always return the entire view area if GPU is enabled. When GPU is not used, getClipBounds() returns the actual dirty area. Since there is a GPU in most phones, it makes the function getClipBounds pretty much useless.